# XML parser for multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, xml

I made a basic XML parser supposed to be work in many browsers by using most older functions. What it must do is return an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of a XML text in a string.

(it's not cool for HTML because it doesn't recognize names of elements like input, div, etc...)

The following string:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html><html><Item1 Attribute1="Value"/></html>"
```

Turns into the following representation array when used in first parameter of call `XMLAST`:

```js
[
    {
        type:"List",
        name:"!DOCTYPE",
        attributes=[
            {
                name:"html",
                value:true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type:"List",
        name:"html"
    },
    {
        type:"Item",
        name:"Item1",
        attributes:[
            {
                name:"Attribute1",
                value:"Value"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type:"End"
    }
]
```

Both interpreting styles. I removed regular expressions because I care about the support, then just made a loop to remove the unallowed characters from tags or attributes name.

```js
XMLAST=function(text){
    var tree,
        expect,
        textend,
        reserve;
    tree=[];
    expect={};
    reserve={};
    reserve.path=-1;
    reserve.textf="";
    reserve.allowed=[
        "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
        "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","@","!","#",":",
        "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
    ];
    textend=function(){
        if(expect.textend){
            if(expect.tag){
                if(expect.tagname){
                    reserve.length=reserve.textf.length;
                    reserve.tagname="";
                    for(reserve.i=0;reserve.length>reserve.i;reserve.i++){
                        reserve.cchar=reserve.textf.charAt(reserve.i);
                        for(reserve.b=0;67>reserve.b;reserve.b++){
                            if(reserve.cchar===reserve.allowed[reserve.b]){
                                reserve.tagname+=reserve.cchar;
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    expect.tagname=false;
                    if(reserve.curchar===">"){
                        tree.push({
                            type:"List",
                            name:reserve.tagname,
                            attributes:[]
                        });
                        expect.tag=false;
                        reserve.path++
                    }else if(reserve.curchar==="/"){
                        tree.push({
                            type:"Item",
                            name:reserve.tagname,
                            attributes:[]
                        });
                        expect.tag=false;
                        reserve.path++;
                        reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                        if(reserve.closureindex===-1){
                            text=""
                        }else{
                            text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex)
                        }
                        expect.tag=false
                    }
                }else if(expect.closuretagname){
                    expect.closuretagname=false;
                    expect.tag=false;
                    reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                    if(reserve.closureindex!==-1){
                        text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex);
                        reserve.parentitem={
                            type:null
                        };
                        reserve.expectend=0;
                        //Parent item (list) of current item search.
                        for(reserve.i=reserve.path;reserve.i>-1;reserve.i--){
                            if(tree[reserve.i].type==="List"){
                                if(reserve.expectend===0){
                                    reserve.parentitem=tree[reserve.i];
                                    break
                                }else{
                                    reserve.expectend--
                                }
                            }else if(tree[reserve.i].type==="End"){
                                reserve.expectend++
                            }
                        }
                        reserve.expectend=null;
                        if(reserve.textf===reserve.parentitem.name){
                            tree.push({
                                type:"End"
                            });
                            reserve.path++;
                            expect.tag=false
                        }
                        reserve.parentitem=null
                    }
                }else{
                    /*
                        ** ATTRIBUTE DETECTED **
                        ** NAME FORWARD **
                    */
                    reserve.length=reserve.textf.length;
                    reserve.attrname="";
                    for(reserve.i=0;reserve.length>reserve.i;reserve.i++){
                        reserve.cchar=reserve.textf.charAt(reserve.i);
                        for(reserve.b=0;67>reserve.b;reserve.b++){
                            if(reserve.cchar===reserve.allowed[reserve.b]){
                                reserve.attrname+=reserve.cchar;
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    reserve.attributes.push({
                        name:reserve.attrname,
                        value:true
                    });
                    if(reserve.curchar==="="){
                        /*
                         * CHECK IF ASSIGN VALUE IN QUOTES *
                        */
                        reserve.valueindex=text.charAt(1);
                        if(reserve.valueindex==='"'||reserve.valueindex==="'"){
                            reserve.valuestart=text.substring(2);
                            if((reserve.valuendindex=reserve.valuestart.indexOf(reserve.valueindex))===-1){
                                text="";
                                expect.tag=false
                            }else{
                                reserve.attributes[reserve.attributes.length-1].value=reserve.valuestart.substring(0,reserve.valuendindex);
                                text=text.substring(2);
                                text=text.substring(reserve.valuendindex)
                            }
                        }
                    }else if(reserve.curchar===">"||reserve.curchar==="/"){
                        tree.push({
                            type:(reserve.curchar==="/"?"Item":"List"),
                            name:reserve.tagname,
                            attributes:reserve.attributes
                        });
                        reserve.path++;
                        expect.tag=false;
                        if(reserve.curchar==="/"){
                            reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                            if(reserve.closureindex!==-1){
                                text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex);
                                reserve.closureindex=null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{//Add text as a tree part.
                tree.push({
                    type:"Text",
                    value:reserve.textf
                });
                reserve.path++
            }
        }else if(expect.tag){
            if(expect.tagname){
                expect.tag=false
            }else if(reserve.curchar==="/"){
                tree.push({
                    type:"Item",
                    name:reserve.tagname,
                    attributes:reserve.attributes
                });
                reserve.path++;
                expect.tag=false;
                text=text.substring(1);
                reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                if(reserve.closureindex!==-1){
                    text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex)
                }
            }else if(reserve.curchar===">"){
                tree.push({
                    type:"List",
                    name:reserve.tagname,
                    attributes:reserve.attributes
                });
                expect.tag=false;
                reserve.path++
            }
        }
        expect.textend=false
    };
    for(;;){
        reserve.curchar=text.charAt(0);
        if(reserve.curchar===""){//End of all. Ignore unfinished rest.
            textend();
            break
        }else if(reserve.curchar==="<"){//Start element.
            textend();
            expect.closuretagname=false;
            if(text.substring(1,4)==="!--"){//comment
                /*
                    <!--* COMMENT *-->
                */
                expect.tag=false;
                reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf("-->");
                tree.push({
                    type:"Comment",
                    value:(
                        reserve.closureindex===-1?//Has closure?
                        text.substring(4,text.length)//Takes to the end.
                        ://Has closure!
                        text.substring(4,reserve.closureindex)//Takes to the index of -->.
                    )
                });
                reserve.path++;
                if(reserve.closureindex!==-1){//Is not it infinite?
                    text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex+2)
                }else{
                    break//Stop because comment is infinite.
                }
            }else{
                /*
                    <* TAG START *...
                */
                expect.tag=true;
                expect.tagname=true;
                //Expect for item end and name.
                reserve.attributes=[];//Reset attributes.
                reserve.tagname="";//Reset tag name.
            }
        }else if(expect.tag&&(reserve.curchar==="/"||reserve.curchar===">"||reserve.curchar==="="||reserve.curchar===" "||reserve.curchar==="   ")){
            if(reserve.curchar==="/"){
                if(expect.tagname&&!expect.textend){
                    expect.closuretagname=true;
                    expect.tagname=false;
                    expect.textend=false
                }else if(expect.tag){//closure <.../*>
                    textend()
                }
            }else if(reserve.curchar===">"||reserve.curchar==="="||reserve.curchar===" "||reserve.curchar==="   "){
                textend()
            }
        }else{
            if(expect.textend){
                reserve.textf+=reserve.curchar
            }else{
                reserve.textf=reserve.curchar;
                expect.textend=true
            }
        }
        text=text.substring(1)
    };
    expect=null;
    textend=null;
    text=null;
    reserve=null;
    return tree
}
```

What can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                    expect.tag=false;
                    reserve.path++;
                    reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                    if(reserve.closureindex===-1){
                        text=""
                    }else{
                        text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex)
                    }
                    expect.tag=false
```

Here you've got a duplicate setting of `expect.tag`.

```
                expect.tag=false;
                reserve.closureindex=text.indexOf(">");
                if(reserve.closureindex!==-1){
                    text=text.substring(reserve.closureindex);
                    reserve.parentitem={
                        type:null
                    };
                    reserve.expectend=0;
                    //Parent item (list) of current item search.
                    for(reserve.i=reserve.path;reserve.i>-1;reserve.i--){
                        if(tree[reserve.i].type==="List"){
                            if(reserve.expectend===0){
                                reserve.parentitem=tree[reserve.i];
                                break
                            }else{
                                reserve.expectend--
                            }
                        }else if(tree[reserve.i].type==="End"){
                            reserve.expectend++
                        }
                    }
                    reserve.expectend=null;
                    if(reserve.textf===reserve.parentitem.name){
                        tree.push({
                            type:"End"
                        });
                        reserve.path++;
                        expect.tag=false
                    }
                    reserve.parentitem=null
                }
```

Same in here.

---

```
expect=null;
textend=null;
text=null;
reserve=null;
return tree
```

There is no need to set everything to null; When you return the tree the other variables are no longer in scope and will be deleted.

```
                reserve.tagname="";
                for(reserve.i=0;reserve.length>reserve.i;reserve.i++){
                    reserve.cchar=reserve.textf.charAt(reserve.i);
                    for(reserve.b=0;67>reserve.b;reserve.b++){
                        if(reserve.cchar===reserve.allowed[reserve.b]){
                            reserve.tagname+=reserve.cchar;
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code, at the start of the textend function, and this code,

```
                reserve.attrname="";
                for(reserve.i=0;reserve.length>reserve.i;reserve.i++){
                    reserve.cchar=reserve.textf.charAt(reserve.i);
                    for(reserve.b=0;67>reserve.b;reserve.b++){
                        if(reserve.cchar===reserve.allowed[reserve.b]){
                            reserve.attrname+=reserve.cchar;
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
```

somewhere half way of that function, do pretty much the same. You should wrap it in a function.

Comment: I made this loop to remove unallowed characters into a function called `removeunallowed`, better, right?